# Bash "declare -p" returns incomplete info

Tags: bash

Having the following script `test1.sh` I'm wondering what is the reason of not getting the full list of **declared** variables with `declare -p`. For `BASH_COMMAND` surprisingly I'm not seeing the value but only `declare -- BASH_COMMAND`. After the variable is used then `declare -p` returns it properly.

What is the reason behind? What am I missing? I couldn't find the meaning of the `declare --` also. What can I do to see all the variables for debug purpose?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail -o noclobber -o nounset -o posix -o errtrace -o functrace -o hashall
# -o xtrace

function trapExit() {
  #here we get the INCORECT declare with BASH_COMMAND having no value
  declare -p | grep BASH_COMMAND
  declare -p | grep BASH_COMMAND
  value=$BASH_COMMAND
  #here we get the CORRECT declare with BASH_COMMAND having the value
  declare -p | grep BASH_COMMAND
  echo "valueOfCommand=$value"
}

function test2() {
  ${MISSING_PARAM?"Parameter is missing in function test2"}
}

trap trapExit exit

test2

: <<END_COMMENT

$ ./test1.sh
./test1.sh: line 15: MISSING_PARAM: Parameter is missing in function test2
declare -- BASH_COMMAND
declare -- BASH_COMMAND="\${MISSING_PARAM?\"Parameter is missing in function test2\"}"
valueOfCommand=${MISSING_PARAM?"Parameter is missing in function test2"}

END_COMMENT
```

Comment: Don't use the `.sh` suffix on your filename: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

Comment: Also, `function myfunc() {` combines the POSIX-compliant `myfunc() {` syntax and the legacy-ksh-compatible `function myfunc {` syntax in a way that's needlessly incompatible with **both** POSIX sh and ksh. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- there are relevant entries in both table 1 and table 3. (Table 1's lesson is "the most important combination to avoid is `function myfunc() {`; Table 3's lesson is "the best option to use is `myfunc() {`").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BASH_COMMAND` is a *dynamic* variable and its value is updated only when you reference to it.

1. Initially when Bash starts, `BASH_COMMAND` is only declared without being assigned with a value.
2. When you `declare -p | grep BASH_COMMAND` <sup>(no matter how many times)</sup> the var is still not referenced yet so it still has no value.

   - This can be verified by adding `v=$BASH_COMMAND` before invoking `test2`.
   - Vars like `RANDOM` are similar, you can try `declare -p | grep -w RANDOM`.
   - Rather than `declare -p | grep BASH_COMMAND` you can just `declare -p BASH_COMMAND`.
3. Then with `value=$BASH_COMMAND` it's being referenced and Bash updates it with the command which triggers the trap.
4. And then `declare -p` can also show its value.

---

`--` as in `declare --` has no special meaning. It just "*signals the end of options and disables  further  option  processing*" though it's not really necessary for this case.